# searching web-client for python that can handle frames

Tags: python, web

I'm searching for a python module that simulates a webbrowser and can handle html frames. I want to use the chatbot Brain http://www.thebot.de/ with python. If you know any tutorials that explain how to use your suggested module in relation with forms and frames give me a links to them please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim,

I suggest you take a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). By default it opens and manipulates Firefox to navigate the web. Its primary use case is testing, however in a pinch I've used it in some of my scripts to get past sites with a lot of javascript or, as in this case, iframes.

The basic usage is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

To access an iframe you can use the following code:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(elm)
```

Then when you want to switch out of the iframe:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You can even utilize Selenium headless with [xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper) like this (code from github.com/cgolberg/xvfbwrapper):

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()

# launch stuff inside virtual display here

vdisplay.stop()
```